# Routing outside of application Angular2

Tags: angular, navigation

I have an app in Angular2 and I need to navigate outside of app.
I Have simple view:

```
...
<a [routerLink]="library.url" target="_blank" (click)="goToPage(library.url)">{{library.url}}</a>
...
```

and I want to navigate to `library.url`, I have method for navigation:

```
      goToPage(url: string)
      {
         //What should be here for navigation outside?
      }
```

Or exists another way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set the global window-location of your Browser in your code, to navigate to your url:

```
goToPage(url: string): void {
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me, maybe I do something wrong?
I've just put `window.location.href = url;` to `goToPage` method and nothing changed.

Comment: Have you removed the `[routerLink]` from your Anchor-Tag?

Comment: Yes, I have. Now I have this:
`<a target="_blank" (click)="goToPage(library.url)">{{library.url}}</a>`

Comment: I don't know why it's not working, but you could try this Anchor-Tag `<a [href]="library.url" target="_blank">My Link</a>`

Comment: looks like it can be your url. Is there a way you can preprend the Url with "http://" ?

Comment: Thank you so match and sorry about stupid questions, I'm new in front-end developing.